# How can I reactively update a value in a component from a store value?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have two components and a basic store as per the docs here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html#Simple-State-Management-from-Scratch.

I want to make it so that when I type into an input the value in a different component is updated by using the store.

Basic example here.

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>Store Demo</h1>
    <BaseInputText /> Value From Store: {{ test }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import BaseInputText from "./components/BaseInputText.vue";
import { store } from "../store.js";

export default {
  // This should reactively changed as per the input
  computed: {
    test: function() {
      return store.state.test;
    }
  },
  components: {
    BaseInputText
  }
};
</script>
```

BaseInput.vue

```
<template>
  <input type="text" class="input" v-model="test" />
</template>

<script>
import { store } from "../store.js";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      test: store.state.test
    };
  },
  // When the value changes update the store
  watch: {
    test: function(newValue) {
      store.setTest(newValue);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

store.js

```
export const store = {
  debug: true,
  state: {
    test: "hi"
  },
  setTest(newValue) {
    if (this.debug) console.log("Set the test field with:", newValue);
    this.state.test = newValue;
  }
};
```

I want to make it so that when I type a string into the input the `test` variable in App.vue is updated. I'm trying to understand how the store pattern works. I'm aware of how to use props.

I also have a working copy here: https://codesandbox.io/s/loz79jnoq?fontsize=14

Comment: If you're trying to update the `store`'s state, you should use `mutations`. Modifying the store directly is an anti-pattern, and you'll see a console warning about it.

Comment: This is for the store pattern as referenced in the docs.  Sorry, the vuex tag is a little misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Updated***
**2.6.0+**
To make store reactive use `Vue.observable` (added in in 2.6.0+)

store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'

export const store = Vue.observable({
  debug: true,
  state: {
    test: 'hi'
  }
})
```

BaseInputText.vue

```
<input type="text" class="input" v-model="state.test">
...
data() {
    return {
      state: store.state
    };
  },
```

**before 2.6.0**

store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'

export const store = new Vue({
  data: {
    debug: true,
    state: {
      test: 'hi'
    }
  }
})
```

BaseInputText.vue

```
<input type="text" class="input" v-model="state.test">
...
data() {
  return {
    state: store.state
  };
}
```

***Old answer***
From documentation `However, the difference is that computed properties are cached based on their reactive dependencies`[.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods)
The store is not reactive

Change to

App.vue

```
  data() {
    return {
      state: store.state
    };
  },
  computed: {
    test: function() {
      return this.state.test;
    }
  },
```

It looks bad but I don't see another way to make it work

Comment: I saw your first answer and that's actually closer to being correct. I changed it so that I no longer directly reference the store value but instead reference the state. i.e. {{ state.test }} instead of {{ test }}. If you change it back I'll accept the answer :).

Comment: Does it work for you? I reloaded the page and it does't for me) You can see the more clear solution with observable (version 2.6 required)

Comment: Yea, it seems to work if make random changes then change them back. Weird.  I like your new solution but I'm not using 2.6 as of yet.  So to clarify the overall problem is something to do with directly referencing a value in the store.

Comment: Updated with the solution for previous versions of vue. Thanks for the interesting question.